# Best time to workout without losing weight? (weird question, I know)

Tags: weight-gain, eating-habits, muscle-gain

I have been overweight before, and over the past year or so, I have 'controlled' my eating habits, by cutting down on processed and junk food and eating food that's better for my body.

I've lost quite a lot of weight now, and I recently started working out. And by workout, I mean body-weight workouts. (http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/09/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/)

I've been sticking to it for a while now, but people are still saying that I'm losing weight (although I do notice a little more muscles on my bicep and more veins on my arms etc.)

I thought it might be because I always work out before breakfast (and I eat afterwards). I did a little Googling, and it is said that working out on an empty stomach can lose more calories. Does this mean it is better for me to exercise after my breakfast?

Oh and yes, I am still on my healthy eating habit. Eating greens, fruits, proper meals (no fast food) and less sugary stuff. May I also add that I'm currently 18, and have a small physique, so I really want to know what's the best plan for me - if I want to get a little bigger - should I continue my healthy eating but instead, eat more? And also that part on the working out before or after eating my breakfast.

Sorry for my really long question, and thanks for reading!

Comment: VTC as being both too broad and primarily personal opinion.

Comment: You meant ***without losing fat,*** right? More importantly, can you edit the question to include your fitness goal: *lose fat, increase body size,* etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, great work on getting your nutrition squared away. The habits you've developed will put on you a lifelong trajectory of health: it's really not an overstatement to say that it's one of the most important things you could have done for yourself.

I'll try to answer your direct question first:

> May I also add that I'm currently 18, and have a small physique, so I
>   really want to know what's the best plan for me - if I want to get a
>   little bigger - should I continue my healthy eating but instead, eat
>   more?

I can imagine that when you say "bigger" you mean more lean muscle mass, not fatter. Getting fatter is pretty easy, adding lean muscle mass is more challenging but fortunately much more rewarding.

Just to address the term "tone", "toned" is simply lower body fat and increased muscle definition.

You will find a lot of commentary online that says "if you want to build muscle size (hyper trophy) you need to be in caloric surplus". There isn't any hard science on this that I'm aware of, but it's certainly supported by most people's experience, especially when you get to lower body fat levels. At higher body fat levels, even in a caloric deficit, your body has a lot of fat stores to tap into. But if you're at a phase now where you can see veins in your arms, you're likely getting into the zone where sizeable muscle gains will happen only with eating more calories than you need. This will increase your muscle size, but you will also gain fat.

**Summary Recommenation**

- Ensure you have your strength training dialed in. Use a program like Mark Rippetoe's Starting Strength (the book is worth the money), and start weight training.
- The body weight training you're doing is great, but minute-for-minute you're not going to find a more effective strength training system than a barbell. Your body only weighs so much and we really are designed to handle pretty impressive loads: barbells let you do that safely and effectively.
- Ensure that you're getting enough lean protein. Whey protein supplementation is tried and true, with [plenty of research to back it up](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18090657). Shoot for at least 0.5 grams (or so) of your total body weight in protein every day.
- The time of day doesn't really matter, other than your own circadian rhythm. You'll be able to push harder and smarter when your body and mind is ready. Some people can do that at 5pm, others at 5am. If you've got a time that works for you, you're set.

Keep going with your nutrition plan, add in strength training, and ensure you have enough lean high quality protein. You'll be in phenomenal shape.

Comment: I apologise for breaking the rules here - for asking too direct/personal questions. But I just wanted to say that I really appreciate your long and helpful reply - could see that you took a lot of effort in your reply. People like you are what keeps the world moving. Thanks for your help! Have a great day & God bless!